# Archiving only the deepest subfolders

Tags: macos, shell, archiving

I have a very nested directory structure where only in the deepest folders are files.  There folders I want to archive via shell with ZIP or RAR but not the parent folders.

```
   |
Directory
   |-----SubDir-1-----SubDir-1.1----File-1.1.1,File-1.1.2,File-1.1.3
            |            |
            |         SubDir-1.2----File-1.2.1,File-1.2.2,File-1.2.3
            |
         SubDir-2-----SubDir-2.1----SubDir-2.1.1----File-2.1.1.1,File-2.1.1.2
            |
```

When I tried to do this not only the deepest subdirs are stuffed but also SubDir-1, SubDir-2 and SubDir-2.1 are also packed to an archive with all subfolders and files in it.

Anyone an ideea?  Tnx!

Comment: "When I tried to do this..." -- Please provide the exact command(s) you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep any folder at all? If not, you could use:

`find ./Source -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ./Destination`

This will move all the files inside subfolders of the `Source` directory into `Destination`, without the subfolders itself.

I tested this on Linux and it works, it will probably work on MacOS too, assuming you are using that based on your profile picture.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Yes, the folder structure needs to be kept because it's the information what, from whom, from which date and what job the files are.

Comment: But not inside the ZIP file, right? If you use my comment and replace the `mv` with `cp`, it will copy all the files from the subdirectories directly inside the `Destination` folder. I recommend making a backup before running my commands, use it on your own risk! If it works, please mark the answer as accepted.